# Get list of new/changed java methods

Tags: java, svn, diff, code-coverage, emma

I've reworded the question to make it more generic; the original wording is below.

How would I get a list of the new/changed methods, either from two java source snapshots, or from a diff of them?

**Update 1**

I found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javadiff/. Unfortunatelly it only tracks changes in the interface - I want to know if the implementation has changed.

**Update 2**

The Eclipse "Java Structure Compare" is good, but it does not have a option to export this information to a file.

**Original Title:**

Check all new/changed methods are covered

**Original Details:**

We are using an svn branch per functional change, and EMMA to get coverage. I hope to filter this coverage, in order to check all the new/changed methods are covered before we merge it into the trunk.

How do I get a list of the new/changed methods in the branch, in a **similar format** to EMMA? (It's not good enough just to do an svn diff, as I want to automate filtering).

N.B. We use an xslt to transform the EMMA xml output to csv. Here's an example showing one method covered and another not covered:

```
#package,class,method,coverage
"company.project.helloworld","Car","getModel (): String","0%   (0/1)"
"company.project.helloworld","Car","setModel (String): void","100% (1/1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use something like the reporting that Maven and/or Hudson provide in this area?